# Update radio labels text when inputs are inside labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two sets of radio buttons. The first is Time Frame (Months/Billing Cycle), the second is Time Period (3 Months/6 Months/9 Months/12 Months). When I change Time Frame to Billing Cycle selection, Time Period radio labels should update to 3 Cycles, etc. Switch Time Frame back to Months and Time Period labels update to 3 Months, etc.

```js
$("input[name=timeFrame]").on("change", function() {
    var tframe = $(this).val();
    var oldtext = "Months";
    var newtext = "Cycles";

    if (tframe === "months") {
        oldtext = "Cycles";
        newtext = "Months";
    }
  
    var tperiods = $("#timePeriods label");

    $.each(tperiods, function(idx, val) {
        var newLabel = $(this).text().replace(oldtext, newtext);
        $(this).text(newLabel);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <label for="timeFrameMonths">
        <input type="radio" id="timeFrameMonths" name="timeFrame" value="months" checked="checked" />Months
    </label>
    <label for="timeFrameCycles">
        <input type="radio" id="timeFrameCycles" name="timeFrame" value="cycles" />Billing Cycles
    </label>
</div>
<br/>

<div id="timePeriods">
    <label for="timePeriod3">
        <input type="radio" id="timePeriod3" name="timePeriod" value="3" checked="checked" />3 Months
    </label>
    <label for="timePeriod6">
        <input type="radio" id="timePeriod6" name="timePeriod" value="6" />6 Months
    </label>
    <label for="timePeriod9">
        <input type="radio" id="timePeriod9" name="timePeriod" value="9" />9 Months
    </label>
    <label for="timePeriod12">
        <input type="radio" id="timePeriod12" name="timePeriod" value="12" />12 Months
    </label>
</div>
```

How can I update the text of the label when the radio input is inside the labels?

Note, the above code would work great if the inputs were outside the labels. What I'm looking for is some jQuery code that will work for the current HTML structure.

Comment: Can you change the structure at all?  For example, it would be a REALLY easy solution, if you could wrap the text values in the `<label>`s in `<span>` tags . . .

Comment: @Ed - I revised my answer to have a solution for both wrapped and unwrapped scenerios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is [.detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) function used to remove and save the input element to `$input` variable, before the `label` text is replaced with the new text. Finally the saved `$input` variable is appended using the [.prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) method back in to the label as the first item inside the label.

```js
$("input[name=timeFrame]").on("change", function() {
    var tframe = $(this).val();
    var oldtext = "Months";
    var newtext = "Cycles";

    if (tframe === "months") {
        oldtext = "Cycles";
        newtext = "Months";
    }
  
    var tperiods = $("#timePeriods label");

    $.each(tperiods, function(idx, val) {
        $input =  $(this).find("input").detach();
        var newLabel = $(this).text().replace(oldtext, newtext);
        $(this).text(newLabel);
        $(this).prepend($input);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <label for="timeFrameMonths">
        <input type="radio" id="timeFrameMonths" name="timeFrame" value="months" checked="checked" />Months
    </label>
    <label for="timeFrameCycles">
        <input type="radio" id="timeFrameCycles" name="timeFrame" value="cycles" />Billing Cycles
    </label>
</div>
<br/>

<div id="timePeriods">
    <label for="timePeriod3">
        <input type="radio" id="timePeriod3" name="timePeriod" value="3" checked="checked" />3 Months
    </label>
    <label for="timePeriod6">
        <input type="radio" id="timePeriod6" name="timePeriod" value="6" />6 Months
    </label>
    <label for="timePeriod9">
        <input type="radio" id="timePeriod9" name="timePeriod" value="9" />9 Months
    </label>
    <label for="timePeriod12">
        <input type="radio" id="timePeriod12" name="timePeriod" value="12" />12 Months
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are already using the [`for` attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_label_for.asp) for each `<label>` so you do not need to wrap the `<input>` elements with the `<label>`. All you need to do it unwrap and you'll have working code. Check it out: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/clarketm/2pjLmftv/2/).

- If you must do it without unwrapping, replace `.text()` with `.html()` check out this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/clarketm/2pjLmftv/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <label for="timeFrameMonths">
        <input type="radio" id="timeFrameMonths" name="timeFrame" value="months" checked="checked" />Months</label>
    <label for="timeFrameCycles">
        <input type="radio" id="timeFrameCycles" name="timeFrame" value="cycles" />Billing Cycles</label>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="timePeriods">
    <label for="timePeriod3">3 Months</label>
        <input type="radio" id="timePeriod3" name="timePeriod" value="3" checked="checked" />
    <label for="timePeriod6">6 Months</label>
        <input type="radio" id="timePeriod6" name="timePeriod" value="6" />
    <label for="timePeriod9">9 Months</label>
        <input type="radio" id="timePeriod9" name="timePeriod" value="9" />
    <label for="timePeriod12">12 Months</label>
        <input type="radio" id="timePeriod12" name="timePeriod" value="12" />
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("input[name='timeFrame']").on("change", function() {
  var tframe = $(this).val();
  var oldtext = "Months";
  var newtext = "Cycles";
  if (tframe == "months") {
    oldtext = "Cycles";
    newtext = "Months";
  }
  var tperiods = $("#timePeriods label");
  $.each(tperiods, function(idx, val) {
    var newLabel = $(this).text().replace(oldtext, newtext);
    $(this).text(newLabel);
  });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't unwrap the radio inputs. The .html() solution works great. Thanks.

Comment: @Ed no problem. I wasn't aware that you were unable. I assumed that it was just a preference.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the text to be changed in a `<span>`:

```
<label for="timePeriod3">
    <input type="radio" id="timePeriod3" name="timePeriod" value="3" checked="checked" />
    <span class='labelText'>3 Months</span>
</label>
```

And then:

```
var tperiods = $("#timePeriods label");
$.each(tperiods, function(idx, val) {
  var newLabel = $(this).text().replace(oldtext, newtext);
  $(this).find(".labelText").text(newLabel);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Saw this question the other day and wondered why you didn't use something like:

```
$("input[name=timeFrame]").on("change", function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('#timePeriods label').each(function () {
        if (val == 'cycles') $(this).html($(this).html().replace('Months', 'Cycles'))
        if (val == 'months') $(this).html($(this).html().replace('Cycles', 'Months'))
    })
});
```